# Binning in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Which formulae in MS Excel can we use for -

equi-depth binning
equi-width binning

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I used. The data I was binning was in `A2:A2001`.

**Equi-width:**

I calculated the width in a separate cell (`U2`), using this formula:

`=(MAX($A$2:$A$2001) - MIN($A$2:$A$2001) + 0.00000001)/10`

`10` is the number of bins. The `+ 0.00000000001` is there because without it, values equal to the maximum were getting put into their own bin.

Then, for the actual binning, I used this:

`=ROUNDDOWN(($A2-MIN($A$2:$A$2001))/$U$2, 0)`

This function is finding how many bin-widths above the minimum your value is, by dividing (value - minimum) by the bin width. We only care about how many full bin-widths fit into the value, not fractional ones, so we use `ROUNDDOWN` to chop off all the fractional bin-widths (that is, show `0` decimal places).

**Equi-depth**

This one is simpler.

`=ROUNDDOWN(PERCENTRANK($A$2:$A$2001, $A2)*10, 0)`

First, get the percentile rank of the current cell (`$A2`) out of all the cells being binned (`$A$2:$A$2001`). This will be a value between 0 and 1, so to convert it into bins, just multiply by the total number of bins you want (I used `10`). Then, chop off the decimals the same way as before.

For either of these, if you want your bins to start at 1 rather than 0, just add a `+1` to the end of the formula.

Answer (score 3):

Put this formula in B1:

```
=MAX( ROUNDUP( PERCENTRANK($A$1:$A$8, A1) *4, 0),1)
```

[image]

Fill down the formula all across B column and you are done. The formula divides the range into 4 equal buckets and it returns the bucket number which the cell A1 falls into. The first bucket contains the lowest 25% of values.

General pattern is:

```
=MAX( ROUNDUP ( PERCENTRANK ([Range], [TestCell]) * [NumberOfBuckets], 0), 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Best approach is to use the built-in method:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214269

I think the VBA version of the addin (step 3 with most versions) will also give you the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to build the matrix to graph.

For the bin bracket you could use `=PERCENTILE()` for equi-depth and a proportion of the difference `=Max(Data) - Min(Data)` for equi-width.

You could obtain the frequency with `=COUNTIF()`. The bin's Mean could be obtained using `=SUMPRODUCT((Data>LOWER_BRACKET)*(Data<UPPER_BRACKET)*Data)/frequency`

More complex statistics could be reached hacking around with SUMPRODUCT and/or Array formulas (which I do not recommend since are very hard to comprehend for a non-programmer)